# Looping a .next() in a while() loop gives NoSuchElementException in one compiler but not on another

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am a novice at coding but cannot understand why it runs fine on my machine, but when I upload my code I get a "NoSuchElementException" on line 19, "String command = keyboar.next();" I understand it has to do something with closing the scanner but I cannot figure out any other way to work it so it loops the print screen and input. Especially since it works fine when I run it on my machine.
Any insight is much appreciated here

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class example1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Enter an ending value");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input;
        input = keyboard.nextInt();


while(true){
           System.out.println("Count up or down?");
           String command = keyboard.next();




           if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {

               int one = 1;
               int ten = 11;
               int hund = 101;


               while (one <= input) {


                   System.out.printf("%5d %4d %4d\n", one, ten, hund);
                   one++;
                   ten++;
                   hund++;


               }
           }
           if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {
               int neg = -input;
               int one = -1;
               int ten = 9;
               int hund = 99;
               while (one >= neg) {
                   System.out.printf("%5d %4d %4d\n", one, ten, hund);
                   one--;
                   ten--;
                   hund--;
               }

           }

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a reason that `hasNext()` exists.

Comment: Java != JavaScript.

Comment: EDITED: I removed the 'javascript' tag - java is to javascript as ham is to hamster (they are completely unrelated) - this wasn't a javascript question.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic , can you explain? I have read through three google pages of search results related to my issue and none of them are useful in explaining a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a scanner that reads from `System.in`. You don't close it anywhere, so I'm not sure why you wrote in your question that you feel it has something to do with that.

`System.in` **does not** represent the keyboard. It represents the java process's 'standard in' stream. If you just run `java -jar foo.jar` or whatnot on the command line (which is its own process, called the 'shell' - it'll be `cmd.exe` on windows, perhaps `/bin/bash` on linux. It's just an application, nothing special) - then that shell will decide that you intended to hook up the keyboard (technically, the 'terminal', which is usually virtualized, for example if you use ssh or other tools to remote your way onto another server, usually a physical keyboard isn't even connected to those things!).

But that's just because you started that process in a command line without explicitly specifying. If you double-click a jar on linux you probably won't get any terminal and nothing will be hooked up to standard in. If instead you start `java -jar yourapp.jar <somefile.txt` then bash will open the `somefile.txt` and set that up as the standard in.

The keyboard never runs out - you won't get a `NoSuchElementException` there.

But files run out. Given that you get this error when you 'upload' your application, clearly, something has been hooked up when whatever you uploaded it to runs your application that isn't the keyboard. It's probably a file, or at any rate, a limited stream.

You're asking for more tokens when there is nothing left to give.

Here's one obvious explanation:

- This is homework or some coding exercise / coding competition.
- You are uploading it to a grading server or competition testing server.
- That server is (obviously - or you'd have to hire folks to type input data in over and over!) running your java app with the test data hooked up to System.in, and not an actual keyboard or even a virtualized one. Nobody is entering any keys to toss the test data at your app.
- You have misunderstood the format of what the input is, so your application attempts to read more tokens than there actually are.

You can trivially reproduce this error yourself. First make a text file named 'test.txt', containing the string `Hello` and nothing more:

```
> cat test.txt
Hello
> cat Test.java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println(in.next());
         System.out.println(in.next());
    }
}
> javac Test.java
> java Test <test.txt
NoSuchElementException
```

After all, this code tries to read 2 tokens from the standard input, which is that test file, which doesn't have 2 tokens. The same thing is happening in your setup.

SOLUTION: Reread the exercise description, you've misunderstood the inputs. For example, I bet the description says that a blank line means you need to exit the app, or if a command `quit` or `exit` comes in, or whatnot. Your app runs forever, it's highly unlikely homework / a coding exercise requires this.

Comment: @deadlight446 okay, so if neither is given then the app should exit, no? You need to add an `else` which triggers if neither `up` nor `down` is typed in, and stop reading from input (presumably, just.. `System.exit(0);`.

Comment: If neither up or down is given, it needs to loop back and ask again until up or down is given. I have been stumped on this for literal days with no real solution to this problem without getting the error, even if I put the loop for in an else. – @rwitserloot